# Server Sockets and Amazon EC2

Tags: sockets, amazon-web-services

I have a problem with the EC2 Instance (Medium), which is relatively powerful compared to my laptop, but I recently made a applet on the server side that accepts socket connections.

The client will connect to the elastic load balancer, then it will get forwarded to any of the servers.

I've tried the server side applet on my laptop with my client applet, and it works perfectly.

However, when I moved the server side applet to the Amazon EC2 instance, it would usually get a 100% CPU usage on the applet.

This is how I accept sockets

```
void listen(int port) throws IOException
{
    newSocket = new ServerSocket(port);

    while (true)
    {
        Socket sock = newSocket.accept();

        PrintStream out = new PrintStream(sock.getOutputStream());

        outputStreamwithName newItem = new outputStreamwithName(out, null);

        outputStreams.put(sock, newItem);

        new ServerThread(this, sock, GUI);
    }
}
```

I suspect that this code might be causing the 100% CPU load, but on my laptop both applets uses only 10% at most.

I tried to debug the code, and everything stops at newSocket.accept(), which should be blocking, so it should not use up a lot of CPU?

Comment: Even if it's using just 10% on your laptop, that suggests a bug.  Ask yourself this - why is it using more than 1% on your laptop?  By the way, how are you measuring CPU usage on an EC2 instance?

Comment: I was looking at the Task Manager, and at the server side it goes to 99.5% and lags everything. On my laptop, I opened both the client and the server GUI, which only consumes 10% (it has a Bluetooth server etc, and a few other functionality), so I think 10% is acceptable with EVERYTHING opened.